# How to apply two queries in one RDP class

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have one technical problem which need an expert to help. :- )

I'm using two queries in one RDP class. So I declared something like as follows:

```
SRSReportQueryAttribute (querystr(QueryOne)),
SRSReportQueryAttribute (querystr(QueryTwo)),
SRSReportParameterAttribute(classstr(ContractClass))
```

From above you will see there are two queries, and one contract classes.

However in method ‘processReport’ of RDP class I cannot refer to the specific query.

The general statement is:

```
query = this.parmQuery();
```

What I would like to do this to declare two query objects, and the first one for QueryOney and the second one for QueryTwo.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot have more than one [SRSReportQueryAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/srsreportqueryattribute.aspx) in a [data provider class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg731917.aspx) for the reason you have discovered yourself.

What I believe you *can* do, is to have the query return more than one datasource, then specify more then one getter methods with [SRSReportDataSetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/srsreportdatasetattribute.aspx).

I have not tested though :)

Comment: Hello Jan. Your suggestion is very useful. I also asked this question with my senior technical and the answer is similar. We cannot have more than one query in one RDP class. 

I'd like to have two queries because I need two sets of 'dynamic parameter' which automatically come with setting 'range' in query. Now, I'm changing the way to use static parameters instead (through contract class) 

Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple queries in a DP class. 
There is a simple solution for your question.
You don't need `SRSReportQueryAttribute()` in your class.
Try this code in your DP class. Works for me.

```
query = new Query();
    if (parameter)
    {         
        query.addBaseQuery('query1');        
    }
    else
    {        
        query.addBaseQuery('query2');
    }
```